# Is it possible to run/execute a bash script command from inside a python code?

Tags: command-line, bash, c++, python-2.7

I am not an expert, so I am asking my question here. I have C++ code which is using openCV modules. I need this program to send an image (img1.png) from a python code to be processed by this C++ code. I have not written this code and need it for my specific research problem.

It can be run through ubuntu terminal:

```
$command_ -option /directory/to/set/of/images /home/images/img1.png
```

My question is that is it possible to run this command inside a python code? If yes, could you please guide?

Or is it possible to call a `bash script` inside a python code which includes this shell command?

I really appreciate if you help me.

Comment: This is off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. Please see Stack Overflow instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has the os module, which enables you to do just that.

For instance you could call:

```
import os
os.system("ls -l")
```

I recommend you create the string and pass it to `os.system()`

```
import os
c = "command"
opt = "options"
args = "arguments"
ss = c + opt + args

os.system(ss)
```

There are ways to bind C/C++ to python which are more involved.  Check the official Python 2 documentation on [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes) to see how to integrate directly.

Edit:
There is contention as whether to use os.system or the subprocesses module.  My answer recommends os.system due to it being in the documentation but you should certainly look into the [subprocesses documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) which offers more flexibility.

Comment: I tried to run the `os.system("sed -rn 's/[^,]+,([^,]+),.*/\1/p' /home/user/workspace/results.txt")`, however, I cannot see the output, it is showing 0 in the jupyter output.